# Googlebot does not find ads.txt file

Tags: web-crawler, ads, google-crawlers

I'm trying to get google adsense on my website, but every time google crawls my website it says that the ads.txt status is "not found." I can view the ads.txt file on many accounts by going to my website (intellical.ca/ads.txt) (Please tell me also if putting my website name is disallowed and I'll take it down)

How can I make it so that the google crawler can find ads.txt?

I've tried everything: Double checking the ads.txt file checking I spelt everything right checking the publisher ID and making sure the crawler can access my site. Nothing seems to have worked and I have asked Google six times to recheck the website and each time it comes back the same way.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. In the future, non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CloudFlare, then CloudFlare is blocking the Google bot which crawled "ads.txt".

[How to fix](https://clashpanda.com/how-to-fix-ads-txt-not-found-with-cloudflare/): Allow the bot UserAgent "Google-adstxt"

Answer (score -1):

Your ads.txt file is OK.
Do not worry.
This has nothing to do with adsense acceptance.